# How to obtain the values of resulting dict. when working with the pandas to_dict() method

Tags: pandas, numpy

I start with a pd dataframe:

```
   Node,prob
0  0   ,0.0035
1  1   ,0.0070
2  2   ,0.0025
3  3   ,0.0005
4  4   ,0.0105
5  5   ,0.0015
6  6   ,0.0085
7  7   ,0.0055
8  8   ,0.0060
9  9   ,0.0030
```

I have indices (nodes) for which I need the values (probs). The indices are:
`array([0, 2, 4, 8, 9, 5, 3, 1])`

I convert the dataframe to a dictionary and run a loop. I **almost** get the desired result.
I've iterated over all the _todict options and "index" and "records" were the ones that worked best. :

```
nodes2 = nodes.to_dict("index")

for i in indices:
    print(nodes2[i])
```

Result:

```
{'Node,prob': '0,0.0035'}
{'Node,prob': '2,0.0025'}
{'Node,prob': '4,0.0105'}
{'Node,prob': '8,0.0060'}
{'Node,prob': '9,0.0030'}
{'Node,prob': '5,0.0015'}
{'Node,prob': '3,0.0005'}
{'Node,prob': '1,0.0070'}
```

Ideally, I would get a numpy array represented by the values of the above dictionary, as printed below. How do I extract below from the dictionary? Hop this isn't too confusing! Thanks in advance.

```
[
 [0 0.0035]
 [2 0.0025]
 [4 0.0105]
 [8 0.0060]
 [9 0.0030] 
 [5 0.0015]
 [3 0.0005]
 [1 0.0070]
]
```

Comment: Have you combined your print output for the result? `{'Node,prob': '0,0.0035'}` given the information provided seems incorrect. When replication this I get, `{'node': 0, 'prob': 0.0035}`. If this is the case, you should be able to get an array via; `np.array([[f"{node2[i]['node']} {node2[i]['prob']}"] for i in indices])`

Comment: @PacketLoss , I get ```TypeError: unhashable type: 'numpy.ndarray'```

Answer (score 0):

If your example output is correct

```
nodes2 = nodes.to_dict("index")
new_list = [ map(float, nodes2[i]['Node,prob'].split(',') for i in indices]
print(new_list)
```

Comment: Good idea to use ```map```. I added a ")" after ```split``` to close the map parenthesis. But got map object at memory addresses: (I didn't know Py had pointers!)                                                 ```[<map object at 0x000001B4898B6D48>, <map object at 0x000001B4898B68C8>, <map object at 0x000001B4898B6648>, <map object at 0x000001B4898B65C8>, <map object at 0x000001B489896C88>, <map object at 0x000001B489896B08>, <map object at 0x000001B489896FC8>, <map object at 0x000001B489896EC8>]```